# Java, Read From text file contains different delimiters

Tags: java, file

I have text file contains different delimiters, after each delimiter(ex: #,#*,#@,#o), there is a specific value, How can I read each value separately and add all values to a single object?

text file example:

```
#index 1
#* Book Review: Discover Linux
#@ Marjorie Richardson
#o -
#t 1998
#c Linux Journal
```

What I've tried:

```
public void ReadFile (String fileName) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    String fileRead = br.readLine();
    while (fileRead != null) {
        if (fileRead.startsWith("#")) {
            String index = fileRead;
            Book b = new Book();
            b.AddBook(index);
            books.add(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not a place we write all your code for you. Show what you have tried and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to create a map of characters to their relevant setter within the Book class:

```
private static final Map<Character, BiConsumer<Book, String>> CODE_TO_SETTER =
    new HashMap<>();

static
{
    CODE_TO_SETTER.put('*', Book::setTitle);
    CODE_TO_SETTER.put('@', Book::setAuthor);
    // plus any others you want
}
```

Then while you're iterating over the lines, create a new book every time you see `#index` and call the setter on the current book for every line that begins with a hash symbol:

```
Book book = null;
while (fileRead != null) {
    if (fileRead.startsWith("#index"))
    {
        if (book != null) // we're finished with the current book
        {
            books.add(book);
        }
        book = new Book();
    }
    else if (fileRead.startsWith("#"))
    {
        CODE_TO_SETTER.get(fileRead.charAt(1)).accept(book, fileRead.substring(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Could you help me to solve this error The method of(char, Book::setTitle, char, Book::setAuthor) is undefined for the type Map.

Comment: @DMohamed The method `Map.of` was only added recently in Java 9. You're obviously using something earlier. I've edited my answer.

Comment: code creates an infinite number of books even though there is only one  #index in the file.